# effective string.Intern from Guid

Tags: c#

Rider dynamic program analysis shows me that following line of code is repeatedly allocating in total about 338MB.

```
Guid subscriptionId = .....
var s = string.Intern(subscriptionId.ToString());
```

This is just snippet from strongly typed IDs, the values repeat over and over, so I guess that there only few unique values, that's why string.Intern

The ridiculous is that I need to convert Guid to string first (which allocates that memory) to find out that this string is already interned and immediately use that intern one. Which seems to me like wasting of allocations.

**Is there a way to get string.Intern from Guid/span of chars?**

Comment: The intern collection is essentially just a cache. Why don't you use your own dictionary of `Guid` values instead of calling `ToString()` over and over? That said, what's the problem with the allocations now? .NET is optimized to deal with frequent allocations of small objects; it shouldn't be an actual problem. Presumably, that 338MB gets collected once there's any significant memory pressure (which on a modern machine might be never, depending on what else the program is doing but, again, that shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: `Which seems to me like wasting of allocations.` The benefit, theoretically, is that your "wasted" copy is eligible for GC virtually instantly. So, in theory, you could save memory _overall_ if you have a large object that `ToString`s that GUID millions of times and stores them all in memory (e.g. a `List`). So you'd allocate a million strings, sure, but then you'd store only one long term in RAM (with a million pointers to it). Is that useful? Well, very rarely. In practice I think the answer below is how I would do it instead. _I've never used `string.Intern` in my code._

Comment: The question is why are you interning anyway, an interned string will never be garaged collected (by design), the intern pool is essentially unmanaged. However a small GUID string will have a short lifetime

Comment: @00110001 Interning _might_ be a reasonable tradeoff if there are a small number of unique GUID values, with a large amount of usage and a large lifetime. But yes, generally not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get string.Intern from Guid/span of chars?

In theory, yes. You could iterate through all the `string` values in the intern pool, parse them as `Guid` values, and compare any successfully parsed values to the `Guid` value you want the string for. .NET doesn't offer a direct way to retrieve the `string` values from the intern pool, but you can look at e.g. [Is it possible to read all strings in the intern pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45312622) for info about how you might still accomplish that (it involves, essentially, debugging your own program from within at runtime).

I hope you see how, even if you didn't have to jump through the process-introspection hoops just to get the collection of `string` values from the intern pool, that a linear search through the intern pool to find the one that corresponds to your `Guid` value isn't going to be a performance improvement.

On the other hand, you could just cache the `string` values yourself with a `Dictionary<Guid, string>`:

```cs
Dictionary<Guid, string> guidCache = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

Guid subscriptionId = .....
if (!guidCache.TryGetValue(subscriptionId, out string s))
{
    s = subscriptionId.ToString();
    guidCache[subscriptionId] = s;
}
```

For something simple like this, the above should suffice. But if you need a more elaborate caching scheme, .NET now includes the [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache) class you could use instead.

All that said, I'm skeptical that there's really any need for any of this. .NET is optimized to deal with frequent allocations of small objects; it shouldn't be an actual problem. Presumably, that 338MB gets collected once there's any significant memory pressure (which on a modern machine might be never, depending on what else the program is doing but, again, that shouldn't be a problem).

I suspect you could just call `ToString()` on the `Guid` value every single time you need the `string` value, and it would be fine.